# PHP mail() working only on some domains

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send out emails with PHP using this code

```
$headers = "From: " . "from@myself.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers);
```

where `$to` is a valid email address and `$content` is the content of an html template.

@gmail and @hotmail addresses both receive the emails correctly. @virgilio.it addresses doesn't receive them: what can be causing this? Some domains are accepting and displaying emails from my server: other don't. Why is this?

Comment: Have you checked the spam folder?

Comment: off course, both in the client and in their online server. I've opened an account just for this: nothing received!

Comment: some servers may recieve mails with delay.

Comment: I'm waiting since yesterday...

Comment: Have you checked your mail logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php `mail()` function uses the local smtp server. Usually if a mail is not accepted, this is because of a bad configuration of your local smtp server. (Open Relay-Access, wrong Reverse-IP-Lookup, dynamic ip, and so on...)

Use the `PHPMailer` (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) class and use a (valid) smtp server.

Answer (score 1):

If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some Unix mail transfer agents (most notably » qmail) replace LF by CRLF automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with » RFC 2822.

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html

I do recommend to use a full featured email transfer class for PHP

Check the phpmailer calss http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/source/browse/trunk/class.smtp.php?r=7

Answer (score 0):

Some servers block the mail due to the 'from' header email address being set to a host that does not resolve (myself.com).

Try using a real email address in the 'from' header.